# TO_DATE() function gives an error when date format variable is 'M/d/yy' and month or date is a two digit value

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, to-date

My date format is varying according to the date format of the user. 
When the date format is 'M/d/yy', it gives error, ORA-01821: date format not recognized.

```
sDateFormat = CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;

SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE yyy <= TO_DATE('" + sScheduleDate + "','"+sDateFormat+"')";
```

//sScheduleDate ex: "11/15/18"
//sDateFormat "M/d/yy"

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems:

1. Like HoTTab1CH said: You should always use `OracleParameters` if building queries (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)
2. You're using a C#-Pattern for Oracle. This might work (Invariant Culture) bot often don't (Minutes).

.

```
// This will get you the Pattern "MM/dd/yyyy"
string invariantPattern = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;

// This will get me in a German-Environment the Pattern "dd.MM.yyyy"
string invariantPattern = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
```

Both Patterns have nothing todo with Oracle. They might work, but you don't know. You must not use them outside of your .Net environment!

What would be allowed is this:

```
OracleCommand cmd = null; // You should have this one already initialized..

// Your Idea:
DateTime date = new DateTime(2018, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59);
string csharpPattern = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss";
string oraclePattern = "dd.mm.yyyy HH24:MI:SS";
string toDateQuery = "to_date('" + date.ToString(csharpPattern) + "','" + oraclePattern + "')";
string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM mytable t WHERE t.mydate = " + toDateQuery;
cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
// Do something...

// But... Better, shorter and correcter(?)
DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2018, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59);
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM mytable t WHERE t.mydate = :MYDATE";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":MYDATE", date2));
```

### Additional explaination

#### Table

```
CREATE TABLE TEST
(
  TESTDATE               DATE,
  TESTTIMESTAMP          TIMESTAMP(6),
  TESTTIMESTAMPTIMEZONE  TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE
)
```

#### C#-App

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;

// Let OPD.Net do the work..
OracleCommand  cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TEST VALUES(:TESTDATE, :TESTTIMESTAMP, :TESTTIMESTAMPTIMEZONE)";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("TESTDATE", d));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("TESTTIMESTAMP", d));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("TESTTIMESTAMPTIMEZONE", d));
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

// Try to manually hit the OracleTypes - and loose the milliseconds..
cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TEST VALUES(:TESTDATE, :TESTTIMESTAMP, :TESTTIMESTAMPTIMEZONE)";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("TESTDATE", OracleDbType.Date, d, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("TESTTIMESTAMP", OracleDbType.Date, d, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("TESTTIMESTAMPTIMEZONE", OracleDbType.Date, d, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input));
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

// Set everything correct (and redundant..)
cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TEST VALUES(:TESTDATE, :TESTTIMESTAMP, :TESTTIMESTAMPTIMEZONE)";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("TESTDATE", OracleDbType.Date, d, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("TESTTIMESTAMP", OracleDbType.TimeStamp, d, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("TESTTIMESTAMPTIMEZONE", OracleDbType.TimeStampTZ, d, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input));
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

#### Db-Data

```
| TESTDATE            | TESTTIMESTAMP              | TESTTIMESTAMPTIMEZONE             |
| 16/08/2018 11:07:23 | 16/08/2018 11:07:23,079714 | 16/08/2018 11:07:23,079714 +02:00 |
| 16/08/2018 11:07:23 | 16/08/2018 11:07:23,000000 | 16/08/2018 11:07:23,000000 +02:00 | 
| 16/08/2018 11:07:23 | 16/08/2018 11:07:23,079714 | 16/08/2018 11:07:23,079714 +02:00 |
```

As you can see. The example-program did choose the wrong types. Without explicit types in the cmd, ODP.Net does it's job correct.

OPD.Net has a mapping for every C#-Type to OracleDbTypes. You don't have to tell Oracle what a DateTime is!

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28375/featTypes.htm

If you start setting types in your C#-code you've got a double-declaration. Your Database tells your client how to convert variables.

If you change the Db-Column from Date to Timestamp you would have to change your C#-App, too! If you got multiple Apps accessing your Db you got a lot of work.

There are some situations, like using arrays with nullable types, where you should set the type, but regularly you don't have to.

Comment: Unless you specify the data type, i.e. `cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("MYDATE",  OracleDbType.Date, date2));` your solution is not really an improvement.

Comment: Actual problem here is, date format cannot be given as a hard coded value. it should be a variable. then only this will be compatible for users with different time format settings

Comment: @tinkerbell No it's not. If you have a `C#-DateTime`-variable you don't have any CultureInformation. YOU decide how to create a string out of it. Because of this, you also have to tell oracle how to interpret the created string. That's what i wanted to make clear.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit It **is** a big improvement, because sql-injections are avoided (obligatory in my opinion) and the oracle-driver/db decides how to convert you C#-type to an oracle-type. If you add a DbType you can modify the conversion, but you don't have to!

Comment: @kara the point is that C# DateTime type is DateTime type, it will always be correct date if you specify it as  OracleDbType.Date. There will be never any conversion conflicts because it's "pure" DateTime format without any culture info that Oracle will always interpret in a correct way.

Comment: @HoTTab1CH I added an code-example which should explain why i would avoid telling odp.net about DbTypes..

Answer (score 0):

It's not recognized because there is no such "M" parameter, here is full documentation for TO_DATE() https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php

Try this, correct formatting mask should be `to_date('11/15/18', 'MM/DD/YY')`

**EDIT:**

To avoid this problem you better use parameters in your query. Here is small example:

```
 DateTime date = //get your date here

 string myQuery= "SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE yyy <= :pDate";

 OracleCommand oraCmd = new OracleCommand();
 oraCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
 oraCmd.Connection = OracleConnectionSource; // your connection

 OracleParameter oraParam = new OracleParameter();
 oraParam = oraCmd.Parameters.Add("pDate", OracleDbType.Date, date, ParameterDirection.Input);

 oraCmd.CommandText = myQuery;
 OracleDataReader oraDataReader = oraCmd.ExecuteReader();
```